# Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/david/geofly/config/initializers/sorcery.rb (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to install omniauth for sorcery. When I run:

```
rails g sorcery:install external --migrations
```

gsub  config/initializers/sorcery.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
    24: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    23: from bin/rails:4:in`require'
    22: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
    20: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
    19: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:130:in`generate_or_destroy'
    18: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
    17: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
    16: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    15: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`block in require'
    14: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    13: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:13:in`'
    12: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/generators.rb:157:in `invoke'
    11: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in`start'
    10: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
     9: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`invoke_all'
     8: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
     7: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`each'
     6: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
     5: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
     4: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
     3: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sorcery-0.8.6/lib/generators/sorcery/install_generator.rb:31:in`configure_initializer_file'
     2: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:265:in `gsub_file'
     1: from /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:265:in`open'
/home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:265:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/david/geofly/config/initializers/sorcery.rb (Errno::EACCES)

Answer (score 0):

I rolled back all migrations and deleted files in db/migrate.
Started fresh with sorcery install guide on wiki.
When migrating, I tried to overwrite files, which resulted in (Errno::EACCES), so I simply manualually deleted these files.
i ran rake db:drop, rake: db:create rake db:migrate.
The production database failed to drop, so I dropped it from termianl with mysql. So far the migrations are working and I successfully migrated SorceryExternal.